# this is the input and i want to print the output as follows: which command or how can we do that?

Tags: unix, grep

this is the input

```
 iws 3211296 3178534   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 2
 iws 3539162 3526750   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 2 4
 iws 3584214 3535080   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 2 3
 iws 3928194 3952828   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 1 4
 iws 3928195 3952828   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 3 5
```

output: which contains 4 at the end

```
 iws 3539162 3526750   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 2 4

 iws 3928194 3952828   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 1 4
```

Which UNIX command can I use or how can we do that?

Comment: so do you want to filter out the rows with 4 at the end?

Comment: Is this coming in from a file?

Answer (score 1):

You can grep for `4$` (the `$` means end-of-line).

```
$ grep '4$'  foo.txt
 iws 3539162 3526750   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 2 4
 iws 3928194 3952828   0   Jan 19      -  0:00 iws_trs 000 0 1 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is coming in from a file, you can use fgrep for this.

Read more here http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/man1/fgrep.1.html

Comment: Can u provide the script using normal grep?